# Php Select While using Photo Gallery and Thumbnail

Tags: php, mysql

I have a photo gallery using php/html
So, Without using database, work great! with photos and thumbnails using this code:

```
<div id="js-grid-slider-thumbnail" class="cbp">
    <div class="cbp-item">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                <img src="img/header/header_03.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end item -->
    <div class="cbp-item">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                <img src="img/header/header_04.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end item -->
    <div class="cbp-item">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                <img src="img/header/header_05.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end item -->
</div><!-- end js-grid-slider-thumbnail -->
<div id="js-pagination-slider">
    <div class="cbp-pagination-item cbp-pagination-active">
        <img src="img/header/header_03.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="cbp-pagination-item">
        <img src="img/header/header_04.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="cbp-pagination-item">
        <img src="img/header/header_05.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div><!-- end js-pagination-slider -->
```

But I want to use database and I'm trying to use Select SQL, to select all photos from database that id area `spring` however I see the photos and thumbnails, don't work

```
<?php 
$sql2 = mysql_query("select * from Photos where photoid='spring'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) { ?><div id="js-grid-slider-thumbnail" class="cbp">

    <div class="cbp-item">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                <img src="img/portfolio/<? echo $row['link'];?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end item -->

</div><!-- end js-grid-slider-thumbnail --><?}?>
<div id="js-pagination-slider">
    <?php while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) { ?>
    <div class="cbp-pagination-item cbp-pagination-active">
        <img src="img/portfolio/<? echo $row2['link'];?>" alt="">
    </div>
    <?}?>
</div><!-- end js-pagination-slider -->
```

Problem: 
Photos work fine
But I don't see thumbnails
Anyone could help me?
thanks

Comment: Please don't do `<?` but do `<?php`. Short tags not always working  as expected.. Also don't use a deprecated version of MySQL, use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: `$sql2 = mysql_query("select * from Photos where photoid='spring');` you forgot a double quote at the end. Also, you shoud read and adapt to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thanks! Still have the problem, thumbnails don't show. I think the 2 while are not correct

Comment: Please check this link (final page, have thumbnail gallery) that I want to use MySql Select
http://diamondcreative.net/themes/ada/v1.0/components-slideshows.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put wrapper outside or while loop as id for JS have to only once like below same for pagination used outside of loop so only show once hope that works !

```html
<?php 
$sql2 = mysql_query("select * from Photos where photoid='spring'"); ?>
<div id="js-grid-slider-thumbnail" class="cbp">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) { ?>

    <div class="cbp-item">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                <img src="img/portfolio/<? echo $row['link'];?>" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end item -->

</div><!-- end js-grid-slider-thumbnail --><?}?>
<div id="js-pagination-slider">
    <?php while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) { ?>
    
        <img src="img/portfolio/<? echo $row2['link'];?>" alt="">
    </div>
    <?}?>
</div><!-- end js-pagination-slider -->
```

Comment: Please check this link (final page, have thumbnail gallery) that I want to use MySql Select
http://diamondcreative.net/themes/ada/v1.0/components-slideshows.html